# Run code BEFORE DOM loads

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML table with a time column, whose values I want to change. However, when I do this within the document.ready(), DOM manipulation heavily affects my load time.

Is it possible to change the table column cell values before the DOM loads?
The code I need to use for the manipulation is -

```
var time_col = rows[i].cells[TimeColumnIndex];    

//Calculate new values
var time_Str = getUpdatedValue(time_col.innerText);

//Set values
time_col.innerText = time_Str;
time_col.innerHTML = time_Str;
```

I would appreciate any suggestions that people have, I'm still trying to understand things related to DOM, so please feel free to tell me if this cannot be done.

#### EDIT 1:

The getUpdatedValue() function just gets the difference in the users timezone as compared to UTC and adds the required number of minutes.

I've tried commenting out each line to see which lines actually increase the load time, and I found that it was just the DOM manipulation that took time, namely the following lines

```
time_col.innerText = time_Str;
time_col.innerHTML = time_Str;
```

My HTML table has about 1500 rows, so I go through each row and change the value of the time column.

Comment: *"However, when I do this within the document.ready(), DOM manipulation heavily affects my load time."* That seems unlikely, exactly what are you doing in `getUpdatedValue`?! There might be a significant delay before it runs, but barring the function being massively complicated, I don't see it *adding to* the load time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree with you, but still told the OP how to do it, I find it hard that it would improve the loading time... I'll be curious to know if it does help

Comment: Why are you setting both the `innerText` *(which is non-standard BTW)* as well as the `innerHTML`? The latter overwrites the former.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've updated the question to include the code for the helper function and the reason why i dont think that is the code that delays the load

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason, you need your code to run immediately after the table has been loaded, you can just place your `<script>` tag immediately after the closing `</table>` tag

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    var tableAbove = tables[tables.length - 1];
</script>
```

Comment: i’m pretty sure you can place it *before closing* the `table` as well, but I’m not sure this has any effect.

Comment: @David Why would you do that? So the tags don't align properly? :)

Comment: I’m just saying... the `table` already avail in the DOM as soon as it’s open. You naturally place scripts before closing the body and you can do that here too. Your answer is correct though, so +1

Comment: @David You would have invalid HTML if you put in a script tag as a direct child of `table` or `tbody` or `tr`, sure you can, but I still don't know why you would. In the case of the closing `</body>` tag, you're not adding it before the closing body tag, you're adding it after the last closing tag in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run code that operates on the DOM before the DOM has loaded.  Hopefully, it obvious to you why that would be the case as DOM elements that aren't loaded are not accessible to javascript yet.

The options you have available are as follows:

1. Locate your script in your page immediately after the part of the DOM that you want to modify.  Since things are loaded in pure sequence, you can manipulate any part of the DOM that is physically located before your script in the HTML file.
2. Use `document.ready()` for your code and just operate on the table after the whole DOM is loaded.
3. Hide the table initially with CSS so it is not initally visible.  Modify it using either of the above two methods and then when you are done modifying it, show the table.  This prevents the table being visible before you've modified it.

If an ajax call is involved in fetching the data for the table, you can further optimize things by starting that ajax call BEFORE the DOM is loaded and just store it's result when it completes (if the DOM isn't yet ready).  This parallelizes the two operations so that the ajax call is being fetched at the same time as the DOM is loading.  Then, when both the ajax call has completed and the DOM has loaded, you can then insert the ajax result into the DOM.

Comment: "You cannot run code that operates on the DOM before the DOM has loaded" doesn't sound right...but maybe you mean the part of the DOM the code operates on?

Comment: @Christophe - yes, that's what the second sentence says.  If you read option #1 it explains how you can run code to operate on a piece of the DOM as soon as that piece of the DOM is loaded.